# Changing background for custom image

Tags: javascript, image-processing

I have an idea to create some application with background changing of photo where man's placing. How i can do this! And do you have any idea (api or libraries) for this issue.

Comment: Do you mean you whant to change to HTML background image? If so, look in to CSS.

Comment: I mean background of image (for example it may be a screenshot from web camera).
I think i must do it on canvas but don't know exactly. So it may be Flash or something else
The main idea to clear existing background like here http://clippingmagic.com and add my custom background

Comment: please try something and when you have problems with real code come back for help then

Comment: Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/bCz92/3/. I wanna clean black background on picture.
its a trivial example. What can you recommend me check when background will be some different (with grey points or something like that)

Comment: @Giffo http://jsfiddle.net/bCz92/12/

Comment: Also see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044889/remove-background-color-from-image-in-html5-canvas