# Remove background colour from an image

Tags: javascript, image

I got a question regarding to the image processing, I am asked to program to remove an image's background colour, so that only the foreground object will be left, however, I am totally lost about how to start it, if I am thinking to use JavaScript, is there any hint for it? Or is there any better coding language I should use?? Cheers.

Comment: What is the image's format? Also, please visit SO's help section on asking questions - the way you've phrased this question makes it very difficult to provide a concrete answer.

Comment: Try the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044889/remove-background-color-from-image-in-html5-canvas

Comment: Hey Aaron, the format is Jpeg

Comment: I think it would be tricky with client side JS because JPEG had compression. A white background is not perfectly white, it contains gray pixels. Maybe you could have a magic filter in CSS3 but you should probably better use a server-side script (PHP/NodeJS/etc. with ImageMagick for example).